# stringing two form values together into a field

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i have a form, in the field "description" on the form i want it to details the product value and pack value from the options on the form so when someone pays it gives me the options they chose.... everything else is working although layed out rough for now, ive put lines in function to set a variable descrip and to set it to + the product and pack items into one field and code in the html to set the description field to that value but its not carrying across, does anyone know why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function calcTotal(form)
{
    var totalElem = null;
    var prodAmt = 0;
    var packAmt = 0;
    var printAmt = 0;
    var designAmt = 0;
    var totalAmt = 0;
    var descrip = null;


    {
        prodAmt=parseFloat(form["prodamount"].value,2);
        packAmt=parseFloat(form["packamount"].value,2);

        printAmt=parseFloat(form["printOpt"].value,2);
        designAmt=parseFloat(form["graphicOpt"].value,2);

        totalAmt = parseFloat(prodAmt+packAmt+printAmt+designAmt,2);

        totalElem=document.getElementById("amount");
        totalElem.value = totalAmt.toString();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert("calcTotal Error:  " + e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {

    }
 {
        document.getElementById('descrip').innerText = 
            document.getElementById("Product: " +'prodamount').value + ', ' + "Pack: " +
            document.getElementById('packamount').value;
    }

}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<form id="orderform" name = "orderform" onchange="calcTotal(this)">
<input type="radio" name="prodamount" value="9.99"> product 1 <br/>
<input type="radio" name="prodamount" value="29.00" checked> product 2<br/>
<input type="radio" name="prodamount" value="49.00"> product 3
<hr/>
<input type="radio" name="packamount" value="99.00"> pack 1<br/>
<input type="radio" name="packamount" value="29.00"> pack 2<br/>
<input type="radio" name="packamount" value="0.00" checked> none<br/>


<!-- need to add in here a dropdown for selecting single or double side print (single stays same price but selecting double side adds £5 to the "amount" variable -->
<select id="printOpt" name="printOpt">
<option value="0">Single Sided Print</option>
<option value="5">Double Sided Print</option>
</select>
<br/>
<!-- another dropdown to select graphic design either 1 or 2 sides - 1 side adds £10 to total, 2 side add £15 to total -->
<select id="graphicOpt" name="graphicOpt">
<option value="0" selected>Supplying Own Artwork</option>
<option value="10">Single Sided Graphic Design</option>
<option value="15">Double Sided Graphic Design</option>
</select>
<br/>
<!-- box here displaying the total preferable without having to click a recalculate button -->
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" value="0"/>
<div id="totalAmt"></div>

<input type="text" id="description" name="description" value="0"/>
<div id="descrip"></div>

<input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="info@creaitve.co.uk"> <!-- nochex required -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@creaitve.co.uk">  <!-- paypal required -->
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP"> <!-- paypal required -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"> <!-- paypal required -->
<input name="instId" type="hidden" value="1243833" /> <!-- worldpay required -->
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="GBP"> <!-- worldpay required -->

<input type="hidden" name="cartId" value="CreaITve"> <!-- worldpay cart name -->
<input type="hidden" name="description" value="CreaITve"> <!-- nochex cart name -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="CreaITve"> <!-- paypal cart name  -->

<input type="hidden" name="desc" value="Print Service A7 Leaflets" + printOpt> <!-- worldpay product name -->
<!-- <input type="hidden" name="description" value="Print Service A7 Leaflets" + printOpt>  nochex product name -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Print Service A7 Leaflets" + printOpt> <!-- paypal product name  -->



<input type='submit' name='worldpay' value='WorldPay' formAction="https://secure.worldpay.com/wcc/purchase" method="POST"><autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return verifyfields()">
<input type='submit' name='nochex' value='NoChex' formAction="https://secure.nochex.com/"><autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return verifyfields()">
<input type='submit' name='paypal' value='Paypal' formAction="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">


</form>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    // Calculate the initial total
    calcTotal(document.getElementById("orderform"));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do u want in the innertext of descrip?

Comment: i ned the values ie amounts from the prodamount and pack amount from the form then set a html description field to that as a string to feed to payment gateway as order description

Comment: Still not very clear. Give me an example of what will go inside desciption text box.

Comment: the radio form allows two entried prodamount and packamount which holds the values... the form is for leaflet print so description would want as leaflet product (prodamount) pack (packamount) and ideally  printoption (printopt) graphic design (graphicopt) from the form as you can see i was trying to get the product and pack to work first then just add the other two after but tried loads of things and cant seem to get it in the description field... ie if it worked in html only would be; description =prodamount + " " + packamount + " " + printopt + " " + graphicopt

Comment: Do u definitely need form?

 if summing the value and printing it in description section is ur requirement, then it can be achieved even without form.

Comment: yes the final version wont be shown to website visitor it will be passed to the payment gateway as a hidden field that i can see once payment is made, ie customer picks a product and selects options, the form adds the total based on the entries and on clicking payment option goes to the relevant checkout... all that is working now i just need to be able to see a breakdown of value of options picked which makes up the total

Comment: see if this helps; https://jsfiddle.net/3rved52y/